# How to print the user birthdate from Facebook_API

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I was successful in querying the Graph Api and receive the user birthday,but unable to print it.
My API call: /me?fields=id,name,picture,birthday{date};

echo $user['birthday'];

I am receiving this error while trying

Please help,i am newbie to PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get birthday:

```
 echo $user['birthday']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

you can't just echo ['birthday'] because it is a datetime object so you need to use a function of the DateTime object to convert to string.

Comment: I got the issue solved...This worked for me...i used $user['birthday']->date;   thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of :
print_r($user)

Available indexes will be printed.

You would consider to test your variable with this 2 functions : is_array($user) and isset($user['birthday'])

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: [id] => 185142354451096
[name] => Cipher 
[picture] => Array (
    [is_silhouette] => 
    )
[birthday] => DateTime Object (
[date] => 1991-09-28 00:00:00.000000
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
This is the array...
I have been tryin to print the date and i receive errors